# working as lab Engineer in Germany

Tags: phd, germany, engineering

I got employed as a lab engineer In a university of applied sciences in germany. I originally come from Egypt. I'm very highly qualified and hold a PhD from the United States , in addition to years in consulting and other licenses.

My employer makes me lecture as well (because of staff shortage and my high qualifications)

I set my own curriculum like the work of a professor. So in another word, I do the work of a professor but treated as lab Engineer.

Shall this be entitled to Salary increase ?

Also, in case of getting a research project to work on, is this entitled to additional salary increase ?

I got employed on TVL 10 , as a lab engineer,  shall ths move higher to TVL 13?

I'm not sure of the German regulations, any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: The rules are laid out in "Anlage A zum TV-L" https://www.tdl-online.de/fileadmin/downloads/rechte_Navigation/A._TV-L__2011_/01_Tarifvertrag/Anlage_A_i.d.F._des_%C3%84TV_Nr._11_2019_2020_2021_01.pdf

Comment: For technical assistants "teaching at technical assistant schools" is one of the criteria for E10, so teaching in itself doesn't get you higher. Do you teach at a level that would require a MSc? that would be an argument towards more money (though maybe only an addon payment without permanently higher group) But some excercises/seminars/labwork can be and is taught by higher semester students, that would likely not get you more). Doing scientific research on your own would be E13+ but again that would need to be the majority of what you do (though you could have two part time contracts)

Comment: Thank you for your answer,  indeed , I teach a Masters course, so I think at least I would need to personally have a masters degree. I teach as a lecturer (the course is under my name) same as other professors and I grade the exams as well. I set my own curriculum like the work of a professor. So in another word, I do the work of a professor but treated as lab Engineer.

Comment: wrt work of professor: the distinction between the professor and someone else teaching a course on Master level is that in the latter case the professor still has the responsibility. If my professor decides I'm to be trusted with teaching a class on x, that unfortunately doesn't qualify me for a professor level wage since I'm considered to work under supervison (at high level). Nevertheless, teaching Master courses sounds to me like it would be worth while to start some negotiations. You may find that your professor agrees, but administration is adamant, though.

Comment: In my experience it's good to have some flexibility/creativity there, e.g. if you find that there is no way into full E13 (which I'd think unlikely given that you are currently E10), you could try to get at least part time E13 for the teaching, or some additional payment or the like.